# Format a date (string) with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

There are a lot of questions/answers on this particular subject, but none seem to address the specific issue I have. I'm also a complete noob, so there's that ;-). I have the following XML being sent from an application to a piece of middleware. In that middleware, I'm capturing the XML and pulling out data. My last remaining challenge is to re-format a piece of string data that represents a date, that sits inside the `<now></now>` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Body>
        <send_message xmlns="urn:xyztech:agent">
            <user>
                <now>2017-11-15T13:38:11+00:00</now>
                <company>xyz.demo</company>
            </user>
        </send_message>
    </Body>
```

I'm using Apigee for the middleware, and need an XSL script to manipulate the date (to make it a bit cleaner - something like 15/11/2017 or 15.11.2017, and I don't want the time). I've tried several examples that I've seen, but none seem to work for me. Unfortunately, being the noob, I'm not really able to debug the errors that occur with those examples (e.g. failing to find the function from the namespace reference), and I'd really appreciate some assistance/guidance.

It would be pretty slick if I could use the XPath that I already have in the XSL that extracts the data:

```
<Variable name="now" type="date">
    <XPath>//Envelope/Body/send_message/user/now</XPath>
</Variable>
```

I've seen a solution for that, but I have a feeling that Apigee doesn't support XPath 2.0, so `format-date($d,"[D]-[M]-[Y]")` doesn't apper to be a viable option, either. Any/all help gratefully received...

Comment: Are you sure you can't use XSLT 2.0 (and XPath 2.0) here? It's just that the `tokenize` function, which you say gives you the date format you want, is an XPath 2.0 function.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (full solution), taking some of what Christian Mosz & valdi_bo suggested above, and a final wonderfully helpful solution and explanation from @friedemann_bach (from a separate question I asked) is this, as the full XSL I needed:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="now">
  <now>
    <xsl:variable name="srcDateTime" select="//Envelope/Body/send_message/user/now"/>
    <xsl:variable name="srcDate" select="substring-before($srcDateTime, 'T')" />
    <xsl:variable name="outDate" select="format-date(xs:date($srcDate),'[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$outDate" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </now>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whilst the first two answers here provided the solution to the date format, the issue I then had to contend with was not understanding why all the other tags were being ripped out. The first (additional) template fixes that (it serves to change nothing, so that the second template overrides "no change" only on the node I select in the second template.
Many thanks to everyone that helped. Being a noob (learning through simply HAVING to do it & get it done), I needed the full solution AND the explanation. I know it's a little "please do it for me", but it all adds to the knowledge, and that's kinda the point. Thanks all again.

Comment: You could also remove the `srcDateTime` variable completely and change your `srcDate` variable select to `substring-before(., 'T')` since your context is already `now` (because that's what you matched in your template). Also, why are you using disable-output-escaping on your value-of? Also a little unsure how your stylesheet works at all since `now` is in the default namespace `urn:xyztech:agent`.

Answer (score 2):

"I have a feeling" is not a proper approach to the issue. Just check whether Apigee "understands" XSLT 2.0.

If it does, use `format-date` function.
Note the way the format is given in the following example.
It provides proper size of day / month / year part.

**Another important detail:** Your source XML uses a namespace
and the script refers to an elements from it (`now`). So:

- This namespace must be included in `stylesheet` tag, with
  a namespace reference (I used `xyz`).
- The `now` element must be given with this namespace reference.

So the whole script can be as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xyz="urn:xyztech:agent">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="xyz:now">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="srcDate" select="substring-before(., 'T')" />
      <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date($srcDate),'[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested it on your source using *http://xsltransform.net/* and it works.

Of course, the simplest way to check is to try this script in your environment.

Comment: This is what I get back with your solution:    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><result xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">15.11.2017</result>

Comment: The date is in the right format, but everything else is gone

Comment: "Everything else is gone" because you did't specify the namespace. See my updated example for a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<xsl:variable name="onlydate" select="substring-before('2017-11-15T13:38:11+00:00', 'T')"/>
<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize($onlydate, '-')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($tokens[3], '.', $tokens[2], '.', $tokens[1])"/>
```

This worked for me and i got the output '15.11.2017'.

- Substring-before returns you the string before your specified string
  occours.
- Tokenize splits the argument into an array on the given
  character.

Comment: How do I implement that against what's between the `<now></now>` XML tags?

Comment: use <xsl:template match="now"> the upper code </xsl:template>
If you do this you can replace select="substring-before('2017-11-15T13:38:11+00:00', 'T')" by select="substring-before(., 'T')"
. always gives you the text of the current node you are in. In our case it is the "now" node.

Comment: That's worked - sort of. It's given me the exact date format I want. However, all the tags/elements have been removed in the inbound XML, leaving only the data, which means my "extract data" script is rendered useless. So close...

Comment: You mean all the tags have been removed in the now node i guess?
If you dont want them to be ignored you need to call <xsl:apply-templates/>.
I dont know your input document and your desired output document. I just wrote the template for extracting the data you want. If you need more help please upload your input (at least a part of it) and your expected output, since I do not really understand whats wrong now.

Comment: The input doc is exactly as at the top of this question. Without your `<xsl:apply-templates/>` the output is just the data values:

`15.11.2017
xyz.demo`

(no tags anywhere)

Even with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` the result is:

`15.11.20172017-11-15T13:38:11+00:00
xyz.demo`

What I need is:

`<now>15.11.2017</now>
<company>xyz.com</company>`